# Wikipedia links to books & Mir publishers

Tags: copyright

In some pages there are links to books on archive.org, does anyone know if these links can be trusted when it comes to not violating copyright rules?

I am particularly interested in a book from "Mir publishers". This publishing company closed down, does that make its copyrights void or am I obliged to buy from the remaining copies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Archive.org has two parts:

The first is the Wayback Machine, which shows you older versions of websites. If you found the book on the old version of a website through the Wayback Machine, it might be copyrighted.

Second, is Archive.org's collection of links. Those are the ones under the title "Top Collections at the Archive". Those should be copyright free and available to use.

Comment: Apparently "Mir publishers" has closed down, does that automatically make the copyrights void?

Comment: It doesn't automatically mean that, but it might mean it. The copyright could have been transferred. Look at the entry on Archive for the book and it should say. Again, if it is in the list of links it is not copyrighted.

Comment: I could find my book under a "Top collection at the archive", so I guess it adds up with the publisher being out of service.

Comment: What is your book? Just search for it.

Comment: "I could", I found it :p

Comment: Could you approve my answer please, if it helped.

Comment: I accepted it but I cannot vote due to low reputation.